# Error in `row.names<-.data.frame using mlogit in R language

Tags: r, duplicates, syntax-error

Here are the steps I'm following to do a Multinomial Linear Regression.

```
> z<-read.table("2008 Racedata.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", row.names=NULL)

> head(z)

     datekey raceno horseno place winner draw winodds log_odds jwt  hwt
1 2008091501      1       8     1      1    2    12.0 2.484907 128 1170
2 2008091501      1      11     2      0    3     8.6 2.151762 123 1135
3 2008091501      1       6     3      0    5     7.0 1.945910 127 1114
4 2008091501      1      12     4      0   10    23.0 3.135494 123 1018
5 2008091501      1      14     5      0    4    11.0 2.397895 113 1027
6 2008091501      1       5     6      0   14    50.0 3.912023 131  972

> x<-mlogit.data(z,choice="winner",shape="long",id.var="datekey",alt.var="horseno")

Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1.8", "1.11", "1.6",  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‚Äò10.2‚Äô, ‚Äò10.4‚Äô, ‚Äò10.8‚Äô,
‚Äò100.7‚Äô, ‚Äò101.12‚Äô, ‚Äò102.1‚Äô, ‚Äò102.3‚Äô, ‚Äò103.2‚Äô, ‚Äò103.4‚Äô, 
‚Äò103.6‚Äô, ‚Äò104.12‚Äô, ‚Äò104.3‚Äô, ‚Äò104.9‚Äô, ‚Äò105.1‚Äô, ‚Äò105.5‚Äô, 
‚Äò105.6‚Äô, ‚Äò105.8‚Äô, ‚Äò106.11‚Äô, ‚Äò106.12‚Äô, ‚Äò106.13‚Äô, ‚Äò106.7‚Äô, 
‚Äò107.10‚Äô, ‚Äò107.14‚Äô, ‚Äò107.3‚Äô, ‚Äò108.12‚Äô, ‚Äò108.2‚Äô, ‚Äò108.6‚Äô, 
‚Äò108.9‚Äô, ‚Äò109.1‚Äô, ‚Äò109.14‚Äô, ‚Äò109.7‚Äô, ‚Äò11.12‚Äô, ‚Äò11.5‚Äô, 
‚Äò11.9‚Äô, ‚Äò110.2‚Äô, ‚Äò110.3‚Äô, ‚Äò110.4‚Äô, ‚Äò110.9‚Äô, ‚Äò111.1‚Äô, 
‚Äò111.7‚Äô, ‚Äò112.12‚Äô, ‚Äò112.3‚Äô, ‚Äò112.6‚Äô, ‚Äò112.8‚Äô, ‚Äò113.10‚Äô, 
‚Äò113.13‚Äô, ‚Äò113.7‚Äô, ‚Äò114.12‚Äô, ‚Äò114.2‚Äô, ‚Äò114.9‚Äô, ‚Äò115.10‚Äô, 
‚Äò115.13‚Äô, ‚Äò115.5‚Äô, ‚Äò116.11‚Äô, ‚Äò116.6‚Äô, ‚Äò117.14‚Äô, ‚Äò117.3‚Äô, 
‚Äò117.7‚Äô, ‚Äò118.1‚Äô, ‚Äò118.13‚Äô, ‚Äò118.2‚Äô, ‚Äò118.9‚Äô, ‚Äò119.10‚Äô, 
‚Äò119.5‚Äô, ‚Äò119.6‚Äô, ‚Äò119.8‚Äô, ‚Äò12.1‚Äô, ‚Äò12.10‚Äô, ‚Äò12.3‚Äô, 
‚Äò12.6‚Äô, ‚Äò120.2‚Äô, ‚Äò120.4‚Äô, ‚Äò120.7‚ [... truncated] 
>
```

What step am I missing here? Why the duplicates in row.names?

Thanks,
Walt

Comment: One of the bits of knowledge you are expecting of your audience is the package name for the `mlogit.data` function. (Some of us have gotten tired of doing searching for things that _should_ have been provided.)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the package call: >library(mlogit) I didn't realize there was more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.

You seem to have some problem with encoding since we are seeing lots of umlauts and accent marks in that error message. Furthernore I am wondering if that datekey column got converted into a factor class?

In this case it it referring to an error in construction of the row.names attribute of the new object, `x`. If you do:

```
 with( z, table( datekey, horseno) )
```

... you may see an a horse with multiple entries on the same day.

Actually there were no duplicate datekey x horseno combos. Changing to factor for horseno and datekey and then switching the "long" argument to "wide" produces error free result with this result:

```
z$datekey <- as.character(z$datekey)
z$horseno <- as.character(z$horseno)
x<-mlogit.data(z,choice="winner",shape="wide",id.var="datekey",alt.var="horseno")
str(x)
#----------
Classes ‘mlogit.data’ and 'data.frame': 18312 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ datekey : Factor w/ 733 levels "2008091501","2008091502",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ raceno  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ horseno : chr  "0" "1" "0" "1" ...
 $ place   : int  1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
 $ winner  : logi  FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
 $ draw    : int  2 2 3 3 5 5 10 10 4 4 ...
 $ winodds : num  12 12 8.6 8.6 7 7 23 23 11 11 ...
 $ log_odds: num  2.48 2.48 2.15 2.15 1.95 ...
 $ jwt     : int  128 128 123 123 127 127 123 123 113 113 ...
 $ hwt     : int  1170 1170 1135 1135 1114 1114 1018 1018 1027 1027 ...
 $ chid    : num  1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
 - attr(*, "index")='data.frame':   18312 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ chid: Factor w/ 9156 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
  ..$ alt : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
  ..$ id  : Factor w/ 733 levels "2008091501","2008091502",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "choice")= chr "winner"
```

Comment: The data are exported as tab delimited text files from Excel on a Mac. The Excel files originated on a Windows machine. These files are from a book by CXWong entitled Precision.

Comment: Is there any way to post a link to the tsv file?